# The direct sum of a family of free abelian groups is a free abelian group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that {$F_\alpha$} is a family of free abelian groups $F_\alpha$ on $X_\alpha$ for each $\alpha$. I wish to show that $\sum_\alpha F_\alpha$ is a free abelian group. My solution:

Each $F_\alpha$ is isomorphic to $\sum_{x\in X_\alpha} \mathbb Z$, so that $\sum_\alpha F_\alpha \cong \sum_{x\in \dot \cup X_\alpha} \mathbb Z$, where $\dot \cup$ is the notation for disjoint union.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: It depends a bit on your definition of free abelian group.

Comment: @DerekHolt my definition of a free abelian group is an abelian group that has a nonempty basis. With this definition, is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes it is. Free abelian groups can also be defined by their universal property. There is no need for the basis to be nonempty. The trivial group is the free abelian group with empty basis.